# Trouble in scraping specific element having same classname using beautifulsoup python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How can I extract text with status information Semi-Furnished,
Available immediately for Family on,Semi-Furnished.

As the div class="proDetailsRowElm" has detail and status information i am ending up getting  detail an status information in my list.

Could you please help me to get only status information?

**HTML CODE**

```html
<div class="proDetailsRowElm">
<label>Details:</label>
<div class="proDetailsRow__list">
<span class="proDetailsRow__item">3 Bathroom</span>
<span class="proDetailsRow__item">3 Balcony</span>
</div>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class='stop-propagation underline font-type-4 view-details-link' href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="stopPage=true;window.open('/propertyDetails/3-BHK-1800-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Rent-Kadubeesanahalli-in-Bangalore&id=4d423330363332363633', '_blank');callDetailPropertData('30632663');addViewedPropertyToCookie('30632663',1);detailViewTrack('30632663');clicktrack('1', 'propertyId=30632663,'+'2', 'div'+',sessionId='+sessionId  ,'Rent','Kadubeesanahalli','Agent','91','Bangalore' ,'','', 'N','35,000','','3','Multistorey Apartment','','','8','','',false,'','',''); trackPropertyPosition('1', '2', '30632663', 'div')"></a>
</div>
<div class="proDetailsRowElm">
<label>Status:</label>
Semi-Furnished,
Available immediately for Family
</div>
```

**Python code**

```html
property_status_list=soup.find_all('div',class_='proDetailsRowElm')
for property_status in property_status_list:
    for element in property_status_list:
        print(element.text)
```

**Above code Output**

Details:
3 Bathroom
3 Balcony

Status:
Furnished,
Available immediately for Family

**Required Output**

Status:
Furnished,
Available immediately for Family

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm by no means a BeautifulSoup expert but you might be able to use `next_sibling`:

```
property_status_list=soup.find_all('div',class_='proDetailsRowElm')
for property_status in property_status_list:
    try:
        k = property_status.find('label', text='Status:').next_sibling
        print(repr(k))
    except:
        pass
```

Returns:

```
'\nSemi-Furnished,\nAvailable immediately for Family\n'
```